# Preview image in my list of files

Tags: android, thumbnails

I have a list of files in my app and each one of them has an icon or image next to the title.
I want that this icon will be an preview image of this file and I've used the next method:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
image.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
               activity.getContentResolver(),
               Long.valueOf(R.drawable.img_file),
               MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
               (BitmapFactory.Options) null));
```

This code doesn't work in my app, there is no picture in the icon.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: what error your are getting? share your logcat

Comment: There is no errors in the LogCat...but there is no pictures on the icons either.

Comment: Log.i("log","Bitmap"+MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
               activity.getContentResolver(),
               Long.valueOf(R.drawable.img_file),
               MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
               (BitmapFactory.Options) null));

Comment: try this..and see what you get..btimap or null..

Comment: I get "Bitmapnull" in all cases ... why can pass this?

Comment: How should `getThumbnail()` know from which file to get a preview bitmap? I see no connection with a specific file.

Comment: you have a list of file...dat means you must have a src of image..or url or path of image..use that to get the imahe..and use library..to avoid outOFMemory exception

Comment: But, Can I not to get a thumbnail from an image in my project? In the drawable folder...

Comment: @MeenalSharma you say me that I must use a url or path of image (a String), but it's necessary a Long in this method, how I make this?

Comment: @greenapps "R.drawable.img_file" is the image file to get a preview bitmap.

Comment: where are your images..in sdcard.

Comment: You could have said before that you were talking about images in the drawables resource folder. And maybe you have no list of files but of resource identifiers?

Comment: Yes @MeenalSharma, my images are in SDCard, but I was testing method with images from my drawable folder because I needed a LONG character (R.drawable.image (int)) and I only have the path of my SDCard images (String). But, I've solved my problem creating my own class for obtaining thumbnail from images. I have thumbnail for images, but how do I get for video¿?